# PineScript: Plotshape when two conditions are met one after the other

Tags: pine-script

PineScript: Plotshape when two conditions are met one after the other

I want the chart to be marked as soon as two conditions have occurred one after the other.

For example, that plotshape is executed only when the Moving Average (5) has fallen below 20 and then risen above 20 again.

So I want both conditions to be met in succession before plotshape is executed.

How can I proceed with this?

I initially tried it with this:

```
    C = 0

if MA5 < 20 
    if MA5 > 25 
      C := C +1 

plotshape(C == 1, ....)
```

It didn't work that way.

Does anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the value of ma goes below 20 then you can set a boolean value to true. If this boolean is true and ma goes above 25 then you can generate the signal. Example below

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="MA Range Cross", overlay=true)

ema=ta.ema(close,5)
var emaBelow20=false
if ema<20
    emaBelow20:=true
plotshape(emaBelow20 and ema>25,style=shape.arrowup)
if ema>25
    emaBelow20:=false
plot(ema,color=ema<20?color.red:ema>25?color.green:color.blue,linewidth=4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it still isn't showing when both conditions are met one after the other. Do I still have to add another plot shape function? Because with your script, it is only replicating the MA5.